# Sublime Text 2 Package for ejs formatting

Tags: format, sublimetext2, ejs

I am looking for a package with the functionality to auto format ejs files. I have already installed the HTMLPrettify. Is it possible to add ejs  as html format so that it would format it as html code? This would be sufficient for my purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add to .jsbeautifyrc file to allowed_file_extensions "ejs" :

```
{
"html": {
"allowed_file_extensions": ["htm", "html", "xhtml", "shtml", "xml", "svg", "ejs"],
"brace_style": "collapse", // "expand", "end-expand", "expand-strict"
"indent_char": " ",
"indent_handlebars": false, // e.g. {{#foo}}, {{/foo}}
"indent_inner_html": false,
"indent_scripts": "keep", // "separate", "normal"
"indent_size": 4,
"max_preserve_newlines": 10,
"preserve_newlines": true,
"unformatted": ["a", "sub", "sup", "b", "i", "u", "pre"],
"wrap_line_length": 0
}, ...
```